# Storing instance on heap and referencing it from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, destroy

Consider the following code:

```
int cnt = 10;
Object* objects = new Object[cnt];
for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    *(objects + i) = Object();
}
//All objects are destroyed here!
```

All objects are destroyed when the program exits the loop.  I think it's because they go out of scope (When I debug it, the destructor of each object is called).  How do I store them on the heap but still reference them from the pointer?  Why is the following not allowed?

```
*(objects + i) = new Object(); //not allowed by compiler
```

UPDATE:
It seems that only the temporary objects are being destroyed. I was looking for a way to store these temporary objects on the heap (So that they are not temporary) but that would create a memory leak.  The confusion came from the fact that I didn't know that an array of objects is automatically initialized on creation (I came from C#).

Also, what happens when I call *delete[] objects*?  From what I've read, only the pointer is actually deleted.  Does that mean I have to cycle through each object and manually delete it?  If the object itself also stores other objects (on the heap), do I have to destroy those objects in its destructor method? (Which will automatically be called when I use *destroy object*).

Comment: Why isn't it allowed?  And how do I store the object on the heap?

Comment: _'And how do I store the object on the heap?'_ Use one of the various [_smart pointer_ concepts given in the c++ dynamic memory management library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), that applies best for your use case. Do not use `new()` / `delete` yourself, unless you are 100% sure, what you are doing and you really need it!

Comment: I suspect what you are seeing is not what you think you are seeing. The `Object`s in your array should not be being destroyed when the loop exits. However, the temporary objects used to initialize them will be. Your statement `*(objects + i) = Object()` creates an unnamed temporary `Object`, which it then copy-assigns to the memory represented by `objects[i]` (alternative notation for `*(objects + i)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `*(objects + i) = Object()`, a temporary `Object` instance is created on the stack and passed to the assignment-operator of class `Object`, with `this` being `objects+i`.

If no assignment-operator is defined, then the default assignment-operator is invoked.

The default assignment-operator simply copies each one of the member fields of the input object into the corresponding member field of `this` (in a manner similar to that of a structure-assignment operation).

So the comment `//All objects are destroyed here!` is wrong.

---

When you execute `Object* objects = new Object[cnt]`, an array of `Object` instances is created, and the default (empty) constructor is invoked for each one of them.

So the loop which executes `*(objects + i) = Object()` for each instance is completely redundant here, because you are essentially creating an `Object` instance using the default (empty) constructor and then passing it to the assignment-operator, for each instance in the array.

Comment: I honestly don't know why all the c++ tutorials I've read haven't explained this the way you did.  Thank you:)